# Convert date string to long in unix shell ksh

Tags: unix, ksh

How can i convert the below code in c to ksh script. Below code generates date from year month and day strings. then the date is converted to a long variable

```
    /* assemble date string */
sprintf(date_str,"%s%2s%s",year_str,month_str,day_str);

/* convert to a long  */
str2long((char *) date_str, 7, (long *) &long_date);
```

Comment: Is your required output from 01 Jan 2015 the numeric value 20150101 ?

Comment: After revisiting the above example it seems to me that it is not getting the value 20150101 . I am unable to understand the desired output. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want it converted to a straight long value you could do it with the following function:

```
# Call with year month day
# e.g. convert_date_to_long 2015 01 01
function convert_date_to_long() {
    date="${1}${2}${3}"
    let long_date=$date

    if [[ $long_date -gt 0 ]]; then
        echo "Numeric date: ${long_date}"
    fi
}
```

If you don't mind using the AWK language within your ksh script and you wanted to convert it into an epoch timestamp you could do it with the following function:

```
# Call with year month day
# e.g. convert_date_to_epoch 2015 01 01
function convert_date_to_epoch() {
    awk -v year=${1} -v month=${2} -v day=${3} 'BEGIN {
        agg_date = year " " month " " day " 00 00 00";
        utime = mktime(agg_date);
        print utime;
    }'
}
```